# C# Split string using regex expression

Tags: c#, regex

**Input**: `String input = "{True,True,False},{False,True,True},{False,True,True}"`

**Expected output**: `String[] output = new String[]("True,True,False", "False,True,True", "False,True,True");`

I am trying to use `Regex.Split`, but unsuccessful with the pattern. Any hints?

Comment: what is data type of input? is it a string or Boolean nested array?

Comment: "*expected output: array with elements*" what does this mean exactly

Comment: It would be more helpful if you actually initialized variables in code to describe the input and output.

Comment: Hope the edit made the question clear

Comment: Please add your pattern. Maybe it's an easy fix.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aL0gbi/1 (match instead of split)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my version:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String input = "{True,True,False},{False,True,True},{False,True,True}";

        var pattern = "{(.*?)}";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        var output2 = matches
                 .Select(m => m.Groups[1].ToString())
                 .ToList();

        foreach (var o in output2) Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

Output

```
True,True,False
False,True,True
False,True,True
```

Comment: I get the `error CS1061: 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You need `using System.Linq`. (Updated the answer)

Comment: I already added that(and reference to System.Xml.Linq), but still getting the error.

Comment: I've added the whole program source code to help you with the error.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
var result = input
  // Remove sorrounding { and }     
  .Trim(new char[] { '{', '}' })
  // Split by "},{"
  .Split(new string[] { "},{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trim first and last `{` `}` using `.TrimStart()` and `.TrimEnd()` respectively and then apply RegEx with below pattern

```
    string str = "{True,True,False},{False,True,True},{False,True,True}".TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}');
    var result = Regex.Split(str, @"},{"); // result is an array of string.
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Output

```
True,True,False False,True,True False,True,True
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/toiwHF)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
string input = "{True,True,False},{False,True,True},{False,True,True}";

var pattern = @"{([A-Za-z,].+?)}";
var yourArray = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

var Result= yourArray 
         .Select(m => m.Groups[1].ToString())
         .ToList();

foreach(var r in Result) {
   Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Your output :

```
True,True,False
False,True,True
False,True,True
```